# Repeated Error message ORCA

Tags: quantum-chemistry, orca

I am repeatedly getting the error message:
[file orca_main/maininp1.cpp, line 17547]: ERROR: expect a '$', '!', '%', '*' or '[' in the input
when I run my Orca script.

My inp file looks like:

```
!RHF STEOM-DLPNO-CCSD def2-TZVP def2/J RIJCOSX TIGHTPNO TightSCF

%pal
nprocs 4
end

%maxcore 6000

%mdci
nroots 5
dotriplet true
Othresh 5.0e-3
Vthresh 5.0e-3
TCutPNOSingles 6.6e-10
end

* xyzfile 0 1 dabna1_freq_inp_gs.xyz
end
```

and my PBS file looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash
#PBS -N Dabna1DSC
#PBS -l walltime=47:58:00
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=32:mem=256GB

module load orca/5.0.3

cd "${PBS_O_WORKDIR}"

/apps/orca/5.0.3/bin/orca dabna1dsc.sh>dabna1_final.out
```

The xyz file I am using is just one calculated from a previous geometry optimization. Does anyone have any idea of the issue? I am getting the same issue with a few more scripts I am running, which are scripts that I have run previously and have worked fine.

Comment: Your PBS script has an error in the last line, you are submitting the .sh file as the input for ORCA, but ORCA needs the .inp file

Answer (score 4):

There were few errors in your input file, and I have modified your input file according to the [ORCA Input Library](https://sites.google.com/site/orcainputlibrary/geometry-input?authuser=0)

```
!RHF STEOM-DLPNO-CCSD def2-TZVP def2/J RIJCOSX TIGHTPNO TightSCF

%pal
    nprocs 4
end

%maxcore 6000

%mdci
nroots 5
dotriplet true
Othresh 5.0e-3
Vthresh 5.0e-3
TCutPNOSingles 6.6e-10
end

* xyzfile 0 1 dabna1_freq_inp_gs.xyz
```

I could not test this input file since I do not have access to the corresponding .xyz file.